# Addition of two unsigned integer result exceeds and has different value

Tags: c#

```
uint firstNumber = 3912039621
uint secondNumber = 3499050777

uint result = firstNumber + secondNumber
```

Expected result is 7,824,079,242 
Actual result is 3,116,123,102

because above expected value exceeds uint's max value of 4,294,967,295.

I come across that out of range is divided by one greater than the largest number of the type, and only the remainder kept. I tried below

`7,824,079,242 % 4,294,967,295 = 3,529,111,947`

I got 3,529,111,947 instead of the C# result 3,116,123,102.

Please let me know how C# is calculating to get value 3,116,123,102.

Comment: You need to use [`long`, not `uint`.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LIuj6Y)

Comment: since `3912039621 + 3499050777` equals to `7411090398` and not `7824079242`, and with the correct expectation everything checks out, i vote to close this as a typo/not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3912039621 + 3499050777` is not `7824079242` but `7411090398`

and there for c# is correct

`7411090398 % (2^32) = 3116123102`

[Here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew9jS0MjA2NLMyFBBW8HYxNLSwNTA3NxckwsijVNeQVVBw0hLy9hIU/P/fwA) is an python example to convince you

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I mentioned incorrect value 7824079242  instead of 7411090398. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Liam what do you want to demonstrate with your c# example?

Comment: @Liam what do you find wrong about my answer?

Comment: @Liam I didn't said that it does(?). What I said is that op got the not overflowing addition of `3912039621` and `3499050777` wrong

Comment: @Liam that op made an mistake by thinking that 3912039621 and 3499050777 adds up to 7824079242

Comment: @Liam, C# implemented scrypt hashing's Salsa20Core uses uint to add two numbers. I want to simulate this behaviour using tsql as a script. I was stuck with this C# overflow value because I cannot modify C#'s scrypt library. After Ackdari answer, I can proceed with my tsql script. I don't care whether C# is correct or not now.